# Британский и английский

Tags: грамотная-речь

Всем известно, что Англия - это только третья часть Великобритании, но чаще всего, имя в виду всю страну, мы все-таки говорим Англия, английский и т.д. Но вот, если речь, скажем, о государственном флаге, то на язык просится словосочетание "британский флаг" (но не ВЕЛИКОбританский, прошу заметить).
Так вот, как и когда правильно говорить "английский", когда "британский"? И почему никогда не говорят "великобританский", если страна все-таки называется Великобритания, а просто Британия - это древнеримская колония?

Answer (score 5):

Британия - это не только римская провинция, но и наименование островов 
на северо-западе Европы. Британский флаг - это совмещение флагов стран 
британских островов: Англии, Шотландии и Ирландии, если на грядущем 
референдуме шотландцы проголосуют за выход из состава Великобритании, то
 флаг скорей всего поменяют.

Английский говорят про то, что относится к Англии, англичанам, к 
английской короне.
Британский - к Британским островам и государству Великобритания.

При образовании прилагательных от населенных пунктов из двух корней один
 из них часто отбрасывается (ср. устюгский от Великий Устюг, петербуржский от Санкт-Петербург, ивуарийский от Кот-ди-Вуар и пр.), так
 что ничего удивительного в исчезновении "велико-" в прилагательном нет.

Comment: >>совмещение флагов стран британских островов: Англии, Шотландии и Ирландии

А Уэльс?

Comment: @Пересвет, а Уэльс возмущается, что ему не нашлось места на флаге. Если Шотландия выйдет из состава Великобритании, то есть варианты при которых английский и ирландские кресты будут на бело-зелёном фоне Уэльса.

Answer (score 3):

Великобританский  или коротко Британский флаг - это общий флаг Соединенного Королевства Великобритании и Северной Ирландии. Многие путают, называя его английским. Флаг Великобритании символизирует объединение под властью империи различных регионов. Так, прямой широкий крест (т.н. «крест Св. Георгия) является символом Англии, покровителем которой являлся Св. Георгий. Белый косой крест (крест Св. Андрея)  -  символ Шотландии. На шотландском флаге этот крест изображался на синем фоне, который также перешел на флаг Великобритании. Поверх белого диагонального креста был помещен символ Ирландии  красный диагональный крест («крест Св. Патрика, покровителя Ирландии). Английский и шотландский флаги появились еще в XIII-XIV вв. В 1063 г. два королевства объединились и возник Союзный флаг, на котором были изображены красный георгиевский крест и белый андреевский крест на синем поле. Этот флаг просуществовал до 1801 г., когда (после присоединения Ирландии) на нем появился красный крест Св. Патрика, и таким образом сформировался современный флаг Великобритании.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, Англия — страна, входящая в состав Соединённого королевства (Великобритания). В этом королевстве есть несколько стран.

Следовательно, англичане могут называть свой флаг английским: они проживают в Англии.

Comment: У Англии и Великобритании разные флаги.

Answer (score 0):

Бритты были хозяевами острова. Они наняли англо-саксов в качестве воинов. Те устроили переворот и правят по сей день. Остатки бриттов - валлийцы (Уэлс) и бретонцы (провинция Бретань, Франция). Гальфрид Монмутский всё это подробно описал.

Answer (score 0):

Бнион Джек - это именно **британский** флаг.
У Англии есть свой - прямой красный крест на белом фоне.
Он присутвует на британском флаге как одна из трех составляющих.